Why is closing a WebSocket in Safari giving me an error about not being connected when it is connected
I have a .NET server accepting WebSocket connections and responding with whatever messages are sent. When I connect from Safari everything works as expected until I close the WebSocket and receive the following error
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected
The socket was connected and as I mentioned I was able to send and receive messages before attempting to close it. It's readyState is OPEN before closing as well.
This is the .NET code I have
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

// Enable WebSocket support
app.UseWebSockets();

app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:8080");

app.Map("/", async context =>
{
    if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        var webSocket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        await Echo(webSocket);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
    }
});

app.Run();

static async Task Echo(System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocket webSocket)
{
    var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
    var result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

    while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
    {
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, result.Count), result.MessageType, result.EndOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
    }

    await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
}

And this is the javascript code I have in the browser
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
ws.send('abc')
ws.close()


Are you receiving the error on the client side or server side? Your server appears to be echoing data back to the client. Perhaps the client is internally trying to read that data and your close() makes the read fail? Do you have a call stack when the error occurs?

@RemyLebeau The error is on the client side when closing the websocket on the client side.
As you pointed out, the only message the server sends is an echo message. Even if I remove the ws.send('abc'), so that there is no messages ever being sent, the error will still occur when closing.
Unfortunately there is nothing beyond this client error
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080' failed: The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not connected

Searching around, I see several other sites mentioning a similar error in Safari in recent months.  So it seems to just be a Safari issue with WebSockets.  Report it to Apple.
